# A question on the Galois correspondance of $\sigma^2$ in $D_8$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, galois-theory, extension-field

In the context of Galois theory the splitting field of $x^4-3$ is isomorphic to $D_8$. Therefore one of the elements of this group is $\sigma$, which maps $i\rightarrow i$ and $\sqrt[4]{3}\rightarrow w\sqrt[4]{3}.$

Now the field extension is the set $\Bbb Q(\sqrt[4]{3},i)=\{a_0+a_1\sqrt[4]{3}+a_2\sqrt[4]{9}+a_3\sqrt[4]{27}+a_4i+a_5i\sqrt[4]{3}+a_6i\sqrt[4]{9}+a_7i\sqrt[4]{27}\}$

Applying $\sigma^2$ to this we see it fixes elements of the form $a_0+a_1\sqrt[4]{9}+a_4i+a_6i\sqrt[4]{9}$.

Now my question is, considering the Galois correspondence , What field does the subgroup $\{e,\sigma^2\}$, correspond to ?

Is it $\Bbb Q(i,\sqrt[4]{9})$?

My confusion lies in understanding what splitting field has elements $a_0+a_1\sqrt[4]{9}+a_4i+a_6i\sqrt[4]{9}$.

Comment: Compare also with [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3195389/some-questions-on-finding-the-galois-group-of-the-splitting-field-of-x4-3). Again, is $w=i$?

Comment: In general if the $b_j$ generate $L$ as a $K$-vector space and $H\le Gal(L/K)$ then $\sum_j c_j b_j \mapsto \sum_j c_j \frac{1}{|H|}\sum_{h \in H} h(b_j), c_j \in K$ is a $K$-linear projection $L \to L^H$ thus the $\frac{1}{|H|}\sum_{h \in H} h(b_j)$ generate $L^H$ as a $K$-vector space. In this context assuming $L/K$ is Galois the preferred basis is a normal basis, that is $b_j = \sigma_j(\alpha)$ for an adequate primitive element $\alpha$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that $(\sqrt[4]{3})^2=(3^{1/4})^2=3^{1/2}=\sqrt{3}$, so the intermediate field corresponds (by the Galois correspondence) to the intermediate field $\color{red}{\mathbf{Q}(\sqrt{3},i)}$. (Quick check: $[\mathbf{Q}(\sqrt{3},i):\mathbf{Q}]=4$ and the subgroup $\langle \sigma_2\rangle$ has order 2 thus index $4$ in $D_8$, since it represents a reflection of the square.)

Alternatively, you could write out where the generators $\sqrt[4]{3}$ and $i$ get sent to under [all the elements of $D_4$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3195389/some-questions-on-finding-the-galois-group-of-the-splitting-field-of-x4-3?answertab=active#tab-top), and work from there.